# What is the difference between 人 and 员?

Tags: word-choice

Part of the news item provided by Xinhua News Agency on May 24, 2022 says:

...全面记述以邓小平同志为主要代表的中国共产党人、以江泽民同志为主要代表的中国共产党人、以胡锦涛同志为主要代表的中国共产党人，从新的实践和时代特征出发坚持和发展马克思主义，...

But what we often see is 共产党员. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 5):

共产党员 - the member of the Communist Party.

共产党人 - a person who aligns with the communist idealogy and has devoted to the communist movements with significant contributions in his/her political lifetime. In the broader sense, he/she is not necessarily a member of the party, but highly likely.

Note, 党员 carries a certification (党员證), offered by the party, through regular recruits; 党人 carries the label offered through the mouth of, or assigned by, the upper party leaders

Comment: So 共产党人 could imply the people under the United Front system as well as the members of the democratic parties sympathizing with CCP ?

Comment: Depends on the devotion and contribution to promoting the communist doctrine, also important is to be deemed valuable by the highest circle of leaders

Comment: Does this rule apply to other organizations, like国民党员 and 国民党人? Or is it just a specific rule for Chinese Communist Party?

Comment: Yes, it applies equally.

Answer (score 1):

人 means `-person`.

员 means `member`.

Comment: So then what is a 共产党人, simply a "Communist," but not necessarily a "member"?

Comment: for example from  https://udn.com/news/story/7331/6339842?from=udn-ch1_breaknews-1-cate4-news. • 第二次是以鄧小平、江澤民、胡錦濤為代表的中國共產黨`人` • 人 （ -person ) may indicate figure

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding:

人： person

员： personel